# Firebase dynamic links adding trailing slash before query params

Tags: firebase, dynamic-links

I've set up a dynamic link in the web console, `https://mysite.example.com/foo/bar`

It deep links to `https://mysite.example.com?campaign=123`

At least, that's what it shows it deep linking to in the console. In practice it's actually deep linking me to `https://mysite.example.com/?campaign=123`, note the trailing slash.

It's not the end of the world, but is there any way to change this behavior? Or is it just a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, turns out that adding the "trailing slash" before the query params is the correct syntax, as pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9017588/954986). According to [RFC1738](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1738) 3.3:

```
   An HTTP URL takes the form:

      http://<host>:<port>/<path>?<searchpart>

   where <host> and <port> are as described in Section 3.1. If :<port>
   is omitted, the port defaults to 80.  No user name or password is
   allowed.  <path> is an HTTP selector, and <searchpart> is a query
   string. The <path> is optional, as is the <searchpart> and its
   preceding "?". If neither <path> nor <searchpart> is present, the "/"
   may also be omitted.
```